# Additional date is showing in Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker

**here is my code**

```
var available_Dates = ["2015-08-05","2015-08-16","2015-08-21"];

$('input.date-pick').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var formattedDate = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'en');
      if ($.inArray(formattedDate.toString(), available_Dates) == -1){
          return {
            enabled : false
                };
         }
          return;
      }
});
```

Html i am using

```
<div class="form-group">
<label><i class="icon-calendar-7"></i> Select a date</label>
<input class="date-pick form-control" placeholder="Jul 18, Sat" data-date-format="M d, D" type="text">
</div>
```

Now the problem is, the result comes with an additional day.

- 2015-08-06
- 2015-08-17
- 2015-08-22

But i want selected date to be the result.

Please provide suggestion,
Thank you

Comment: show us the desired output

Comment: dates are coming with 2015-08-06, 2015-08-17, 2015-08-22, But i have selected 2015-08-05, 2015-08-16, 2015-08-21. So as you can see one additional date is coming.

Comment: ok, add your html, it would help us working on your code

Comment: i have edited with html